# Examples of non-orderable fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, order-theory, ordered-fields

I wish to find examples of non-orderable fields. We know that fields with finite characteristics cannot be ordered, especially finite fields. Also $\mathbb{C}$ - the field of complex numbers cannot be ordered. 
Every time whenever $0$ can be written as a sum of squares, then the field is not orderable. If $0=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$, then, every square is positive in an ordered field, and this would imply $0>0$, thus $>$ would not be an order.
What are some more examples of non-orderable fields?
Explicitly: We wish to find $(F,+,\cdot,0,1)$ on which we can't put a relation $<$ such that
$$\forall x,y,z\in F: x<y \Rightarrow x+z<y+z$$
$$\forall x,y\in F: (x>0 \wedge y > 0) \Rightarrow x\cdot y > 0$$

Comment: According to the theory of [formally real fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_real_field), a field admits an ordering if and only if $-1$ is not a sum of squares (this requires Zorn's lemma). This is equivalent to saying that $0$ is not a sum of nonzero squares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A field is orderable if and only if $-1$ is not a sum of squares (equivalently, if and only if $0$ is not a sum of nonzero squares).

These fields are called [formally real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_real_field).

Let $F$ be a formally real field. We will show that it is orderable. Call a subset $P\subseteq F$ a *prepositive cone* if it is closed under addition and multiplication, contains all squares, and does not contain $-1$.

Since $F$ is formally real, the set of all sums of squares is a prepositive cone. It is easy to see that this implies that the family of all prepositice cones in $F$ satisfies the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma (because it is nonempty, and the upper bound of a chain is simply the union), so there is a maximal prepositive cone $P$.

We claim that $P$ is a positive cone, i.e. it has the property that for every $a\in F$, either $a\in P$ or $-a\in P$. Indeed, suppose $a,-a\notin P$. Then by maximality of $P$, there is no prepositive cone containing $P$ with $a$ in it, so there are some $p_1,p_2\in P$ such that $p_1+ap_2=-1$ (note that since $P$ already contains all squares, the set of these expressions is closed under multiplication and addition) and likewise, we have $p_1',p_2'$ such that $p_1'-ap_2'=-1$.  Then 
$$
\begin{split}
(-1)\cdot p_2 + (-1)\cdot p_2'&=p_1p_2'+ap_2p_2'+p_2p_1'-ap_2p_2'\\ 
& =p_1p_2'+p_2p_1'\in P.
\end{split}$$

On the other hand, $p_2+p_2'\in P$ and the square $(p_2+p_2')^{-2}\in P$, so their product $(p_2+p_2')^{-1}\in P$, so this implies that $(-p_2-p_2')\cdot (p_2+p_2')^{-1}=-1\in P$, a contradiction.

Now, using the fact that $P$ is a positive cone, you can show that the relation $a\leq b$ iff $b-a\in P$ is an ordering.

Comment: Thanks for these facts, I will find those useful, but I was rather looking for some explicit examples of non-orderable fields other than $\mathbb{C}$ and fields of finite characteristics.

Comment: @MichalDvořák: For one, any extension of ${\mathbf Q}[i]$. But I suppose you are interested in examples where $-1$ is not a square.

Comment: just for clarification, does prepositive cone contain $0$?

Comment: $0$ is a square, so yes. To get a strict ordering just say that $a<b$ if $a\neq b$ and $b-a\in P$. Or just replace the notion of a prepositive cone with the notion of a strictly prepositive cone, as one which does not contain $0$, and contains all nonzero squares.

Comment: @MichalDvořák: another funny characterisation of formally real fields is that a field $F$ is formally real iff there is some $K$ such that $F\subseteq K\subseteq \overline F$ (where $\overline F$ is the algebraic closure of $F$) and $[\overline{F}:K]$ is finite.

Comment: Uhm, $F=\mathbb{C}$ is a counterexample for your claim, or does your $\subseteq$ forbid equality? Basically, everytime $F$ has a finite, but nontrivial, extension which makes it algebraically closed? Am i saying it right?

Comment: @MichalDvořák: Sorry, I meant $K$ to be nontrivial in $\overline F$. So basically every time $F$ has a (non-algebraically closed) extension over which the algebraic closure is finite. This is because real *closed* fields are characterised as those which are not algebraically closed, but such that algebraic closures are finite extensions.